# Restricting nested template parameter type

Tags: c++, c++17

I want a way so that the parameter of a template class restricts the type of the parameter passed to an additional template class.  The example below shows one attempt that didn't work.

The biggest requirement is that the enum value passed to c2 is restricted to the type of the first parameter passed to c1 so that `o1` compiles and `o2` fails.  The second template parameter to c1 could be other types, but I only put a single type in this example.

Also, the type passed as a second parameter to c1 could have more than one template parameter.

```
enum class e1 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};
enum class e2 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct c1 {
};
template <???>
struct c2 {
};

c1<e1, c2<e1::a>> o1; // Compiles
c1<e1, c2<e2::a>> o2; // Error
```

I'm unable to use C++20 features.

Comment: @AndyG even though constraints are good, they're available since C++20, which is not included in the question.

Comment: @AndyG I couldn't figure out how to use enable_if for this.

Comment: Is second template argument always supposed to be `c2<something>`?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what exactly is supposed to be restricted.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I changed it so that the Compiles and Error lines both have c1 as the outer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using partial template specialization.

The trick is to only declare `c1` and then only define a partial specialization that respects your requirements.

```
#include <cstddef>

enum class e1 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};
enum class e2 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};


template <auto E>
struct c2 { };

// Declare C1
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct c1;

// Partial specialization 
template <typename T1, template<T1> typename T2, T1 E>
struct c1<T1, T2<E>> { };

c1<e1, c2<e1::a>> o1; // Compiles
c1<e1, c2<e2::a>> o2; // Error
```

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:26,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:26,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0Aenum+class+e1+:+size_t+%7B%0A++++a,%0A++++b%0A%7D%3B%0Aenum+class+e2+:+size_t+%7B%0A++++a,%0A++++b%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cauto+E%3E%0Astruct+c2+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0A//+Declare+C1%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T1,+typename+T2%3E%0Astruct+c1%3B%0A%0A//+Partial+specialization+%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T1,+template%3CT1%3E+typename+T2,+T1+E%3E%0Astruct+c1%3CT1,+T2%3CE%3E%3E+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce1::a%3E%3E+o1%3B+//+Compiles%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce2::a%3E%3E+o2%3B+//+Error%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g132,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),runtimeTools:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:0,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Here `c1` will use the specialization if possible. Otherwise, it will use the undefined general template for `c1` and produce a compiler error.

In `template <typename T1, template<T1> typename T2, T1 E>` the first argument `T1` is any type (in this case, it is the enum `e1`). The second argument is any type template which has exactly 1 argument of type `T1`. And the final arugment is any enum value of type `T1` (a value of your enum `e1`).

---

The comments asked about doing this but with `c1` being a variadic template.

One way to achieve this is to move the partial specialization trick into a separate trait, and then perform a `static_assert` using expression folding to check each variadic template argument with that trait.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

enum class e1 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};
enum class e2 : size_t {
    a,
    b
};


template <auto E>
struct c2 { };

template <auto E>
struct c3 { };

// General template defaults to `false` (type not validated)
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct c1_validate : std::false_type {};

// When the type matches the specialization, it's `true` (type is validaed)
template <typename T1, template<T1> typename T2, T1 E>
struct c1_validate<T1, T2<E>> : std::true_type {};


template <typename T1, typename ... Tn>
struct c1
{
    static_assert((... && c1_validate<T1, Tn>::value));    
};

c1<e1, c2<e1::a>> o1; // Compiles
c1<e1, c2<e2::a>> o2; // Error
c1<e1, c2<e1::a>, c3<e1::b>> o3; // Compiles
c1<e1, c2<e1::a>, c3<e2::b>> o4; // Error
```

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:18,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:18,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:18,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:18,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Aenum+class+e1+:+size_t+%7B%0A++++a,%0A++++b%0A%7D%3B%0Aenum+class+e2+:+size_t+%7B%0A++++a,%0A++++b%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cauto+E%3E%0Astruct+c2+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cauto+E%3E%0Astruct+c3+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T1,+typename+T2%3E%0Astruct+c1_validate+:+std::false_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T1,+template%3CT1%3E+typename+T2,+T1+E%3E%0Astruct+c1_validate%3CT1,+T2%3CE%3E%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T1,+typename+...+Tn%3E%0Astruct+c1%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert((...+%26%26+c1_validate%3CT1,+Tn%3E::value))%3B++++%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce1::a%3E%3E+o1%3B+//+Compiles%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce2::a%3E%3E+o2%3B+//+Error%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce1::a%3E,+c3%3Ce1::b%3E%3E+o3%3B+//+Compiles%0Ac1%3Ce1,+c2%3Ce1::a%3E,+c3%3Ce2::b%3E%3E+o4%3B+//+Error%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g132,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,overrides:!(),runtimeTools:!(),source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:0,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Is there a way to do this that would allow c1 to be a variadic template without having to have a partial specialization for all possible cases?

Comment: @Graznarak It depends in what sense. Do you mean to have `c1` but with any number of additional type arguments with the same requirements as for `T2`?

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to have specialisation, you can do it via enable_if if you have support from `c2`:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2,
          typename U = typename T2::test<T1>,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<U::value>>
struct c1 {
};

template <auto x>
struct c2 {
    template <typename Y>
    struct test : std::is_same<Y, decltype(x)> {
    };
};

c1<e1, c2<e1::a>> o1; // Compiles
c1<e1, c2<e2::a>> o2; // Error
```

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/b4fdaxb5d)